# Intersection of nested open sets in compact Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, uniform-spaces

Let $U$ be an open subset of compact Hausdorff space $X$. Choose a non-empty subset $U_1$ in $X$ with $\overline{U}_1\subseteq U$. Repeating this construction without end, we can then find a sequence of open non-empty sets $\{U_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $X$ with $U_{n+1}\subseteq \overline{U}_{n+1}\subseteq U_n$.

$X$ is a compact Hausdorff space but it may be not metrizable. Can I say that $\bigcap _{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n\neq \emptyset$?

Pease help me to know it.

Comment: Yes: $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\operatorname{cl}U_n$ because of the nesting, and $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\operatorname{cl}U_n\ne\varnothing$, since $X$ is compact.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we have $D = \bigcap _{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n \ne \emptyset$.

In fact, since $U_{n+1}\subset \overline{U}_{n+1}\subset U_n$, we get
$$D  = \bigcap _{n\in\mathbb{N}} \overline{U}_n .$$
The family $\{ \overline{U}_n \}$  clearly has the *finite intersection property* which means that each finite intersection of members is non-empty. It is well-known that a space $X$ is compact iff any family of *closed* subsets which has the finite intersection property has a non-empty intersection.